# display:flex not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I am using the following code to have two boxes side by side of the same height:

```
<style>
.row {display:flex;}
.col {flex:1;}  
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col content">some content</div>
  <div class="col content raw">some other content</div>
</div>
```

This worked perfectly in Firefox, but I'm working on the mobile version of my site and added `box-sizing:border-box;` to my code. This messed up with the flex for some reason, so I ended up setting `box-sizing` to `content-box` on most elements again and this fixed it. However, I just realized that the code doesn't work on Chrome, whether desktop or mobile, whether my `box-sizing` lines are there or not, and I can't figure out what isn't working. The fact that I'm working on a mobile site but that nothing shows up using Chrome really bothers me.

For the live problem, the page without the `box-sizing` is [here](http://kach.olympe.in/llsif/ccl.php) and the (supposed to be) mobile-friendly one is [here](http://kach.olympe.in/llsif/m_ccl.php).
Everything works fine on Firefox in both, and the mobile preview on Firefox shows it perfectly too. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: CSS Flexbox, AFAIC, basically doesn't work in webkit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change your .row to:

```
.row {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You may also want to report this bug to team behind Chrome.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it, and still works under Firefox too! I'll do. Working on multiple browsers is hell.

Comment: This is one of the issues that haven't been fixed to this date in Chrome: [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: You should add "." to "row" because it is the right css selector for a class while without it select an element/tag, <row> is not present.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you didn't clear the floats.

```css
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
```

Just add

```css
.row {
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="row">Content</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for reminding me of this! I actually had the header on `float:left;` because of previous code I was using, but this is actually 100% useless now, so removing the float actually made my other code with `display:flex;` work again. So no need for a clear, but I fixed the problem!