# Scaling images in flexbox

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I have several images with different sizes within a row. The images should be sized automatically to fill the available space while keeping their aspect ratio.

If possible, their actual visual size should be in relation to their original size. With that I mean: A large image should be larger in the scaled version as a smaller image.

```css
.Container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
</div>
```

A fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ej5au8os/

In Firefox 62 I get the result I want.

[image: Firefox-Screenshot of the result that I want]

Chrome and Edge simply doesn't seem to scale the images at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: Search for css keyword browser compatibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540750/displayflex-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your images inside blocks.
You might want to use an autoprefixer for cross browser compatibility.

Global support: **95.71%** [(source)](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
.Container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

> Tested with **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Edge**

Comment: Wow, that was a really fast answer! Thanks Quentin. With your solution, the images all have the same height, which is not exactly what I want. But using your suggested wrapper and my original CSS looks like the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted all the images to get the same size.

Comment: I edited my answer. Just remove the `flex property` and that's it!

Answer (score 2):

Images as flex items are notoriously quirky. Don't make them flex items. Wrap them in divs.

Here's all you need (your CSS was fine, just got rid of a few unnecessary rules):

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://klotzen-statt-kleckern.de/tmp/logo-g.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ej5au8os/4/)

Comment: thanks for your support. Using the wrapper works fine. Marked the answer from Quentin as correct, simply because he was first (same solution).

Comment: Accept whichever answer you prefer. That's totally up to you. But just note, it was not the same solution. The CSS was different. Mine worked. His didn't. After I posted my answer, he updated his CSS to match mine (check the edit history). No big deal. Just for the record.

Comment: I did not edit my answer to match yours, but the OP's question. I was wrong about his expectations so I "corrected" my answer. Sorry that you take it badly.

Comment: I did not take it badly. Read my comment again, especially the part where I say it's "no big deal". I was responding to the OP's comment and pointing out what actually happened. The fact is that you did edit your answer to match mine. That's just a fact. Whether you did that on purpose or not is a different question. @QuentinVeron